Is `*this = *obj` safe to use in C++?
I have following function:
HttpRequest::HttpRequest(const std::string& request) {
    HttpRequest* req = HttpRequest::parse(request); // Returns dynamically allocated object
    if (req == nullptr) {
        throw HttpException("Invalid request");
    }
    *this = *req;
}

But is *this = *req safe to use? Won't it create memory leak?
UPD: There was a lot of questions about HttpRequest, so I decided to post copy method and destructor here:
HttpRequest& HttpRequest::operator=(const HttpRequest& other) {
    if (this != &other) {
        this->method = other.method;
        this->uri = other.uri;
        // And other fields...
    }
    return *this;
}

~HttpRequest() {
    // Nothing there (There are nothing to delete)
}

static HttpRequest* parse(const std::string& request) {
    // I haven't implemented it yet...
    // I guess it will contain code like this:
    // *Parsing*
    HttpRequest* req = new HttpRequest();
    req.method = "GET"; 
    // *And other fields*
    return req;
}

Also, you can view full code on pastebin:

HttpRequest.h - https://pastebin.com/p2UQDtaN
HttpRequest.cpp - https://pastebin.com/vcmXkix8


Do you ask in general or specifically about HttpRequest?

Why do you think it creates a memory leak if all the special member functions (including the destructor and the copy assignment operator) are properly implemented?

It cannot be determined if operator = is safe to use for HttpRequest without seeing HttpRequest and/or the implementation of the user-defined assignment operator.

@anatolyg, in general

@WeijunZhou I guess OP is concerned that the pointer returned from HttpRequest::parse is dynamically allocated, and since it is not deleted it will leak.

struct HttpRequest { int x; };  -- It is perfectly safe to use =.  This is why you need to post what HttpRequest is.

@WeijunZhou, I'm afraid it's no delete req here

@Minuta18 -- I see no call to new in the code you posted.  Just because there is a pointer being used doesn't mean any memory was allocated dynamically.  This is why a [mcve] is important.

I think the details of HttpRequest class are not important. This question can be answered for any user-defined class like this.

@anatolyg isn't the issue of the leak dependant on whether HttpRequest::parse returns a pointer to a dynamically allocated object ?

This question can be answered for any user-defined class like this -- What answer do you propose?  Yes it is safe?  No it isn't safe?  I think the details are important.

@Minuta18 so I decided to post copy method and destructor here: -- This is still not complete.  The reason is that you left code out of the assignment operator.  What if you didn't copy all of the members correctly?  Second, if there was nothing to delete, why did you write a user-defined assignment operator?   What was wrong with the compiler default version of the assignment operator?

Instead of pastebin, you should place just HttpRequest into the question.  Secondly, and as I suspected, there is absolutely no need to write a user-defined assignment operator.  All of the members are safely copyable without any "help" from the programmer.  So is it safe to use?  You made it potentially unsafe by attempting to write a user-defined assignment operator when it was totally unnecessary, when the compiler default works without any bugs.  What if you introduced a bug by doing so?

@wohlstad yes, exactly that. This consideration is a part of answer, not a part of question. I can't write a proper answer right now; I think it should explain what happens in the general case and not limit to one person's situation.

A question has to be self-contained, meaning it must not rely on external links to make sense. Since the correctness of the snippet depends on what HttpRequest::parse is, you should post it here. See also [mre].

"//It isn't implemented yet". Then I see no reason for parse() to return a pointer. Just return an object. The semantic of C++ is mostly value-based and you shouldn't use a pointer unless necessary.

@WeijunZhou, If parser find a error in request, it'll return nullptr

C++ is not forgiving. If proper constructors are there, it will be safe in the matter of copying. Now judging from the fact that these TTP requests likely call external code (like WinInet for example), it doens't seem that it is safe, and even if it is, it won't be long.

In that case, std::optional<HttpRequest> is a more reasonable choice.

I would drop HttpRequest::HttpRequest(const std::string& request) constructor, since explicit use of factory HttpRequest::parse(const std::string& request) will make code mode using such API more readable. I would just tweak HttpRequest::parse(const std::string& request) to return a value not a pointer.

static HttpRequest* parse(...) is returning an unmanaged raw pointer, which is also an owning pointer.  It should be static std::unique_ptr<HttpRequest> parse(...) which will have an owning smart-pointer.  In modern C++, there's very few situations where new is needed, and this isn't one of them.

The phrase *this = *obj; is not safe to use when the obj pointer is invalid. Dereferencing invalid pointers is Undefined Behavior and usually not safe.

I think the main pieces of information missing from this question are a statement of which memory you think would leak, and an explanation of why, which could include a proposal for how the suspected leak could be fixed. Otherwise, you get a lot of noise in the comments as people come up with their own guesses as to what you see.

Given a properly designed class, *this = /*anything*/; is safe.
Your class isn't designed properly, in particular operator= isn't written correctly (it's unclear why you made one in the first place, since it behaves almost exactly like the implicitly generated one). It behaves incorrectly always, not only when used here. (It doesn't delete the old contents, and the new contents get shared between two class instances, so when one of them dies, the other ends up with dangling pointers; look up "the rule of three").
You should stop calling new and delete manually and use smart pointers (std::unique_ptr in this case), or even store objects by value if possible. Then remove custom copy/move constructors and copy assignments, they shouldn't be needed in your case (and they are an advanced feature, having to use them for high-level code suggests a design mistake).

Since you mention the rule of three, I'll mention also the rule of zero — consider using the automatically generated versions of special methods instead of defining them manually.

Short answer: the code contains a memory leak. Add delete req after *this = *req. You need this because parse does new HttpRequest (this is an educated guess) and you need delete for each new.
Long answer: if you redesign your code, you won't need such questionable lines of code. See comments for more information.

Even if delete req; is added, it would still have a memory leak in the case of exceptions. That's why it is preferred to return a std::optional or std::expected.

You should definitely write an answer which shows how to do that. I like this idea the best, and the answers we have here are a bit too low on code.

The way your class is currently defined does not need any special treatment in the special member functions. I would just use the rule of zero and change parse() to return a std::optional<HttpRequest> (requires C++17).
Your class in the PasteBin currently just contain some std::strings and a std::map, and those classes do dynamic allocations themselves and the size of your class is not really big, so it is safe to allocate an object of the class itself on the stack and there is no need for dynamic allocation that I can see.
As I have commented in the question and also pointed out by the answer by HolyBlackCat, in a correctly implemented class, *this=... is always safe by itself. Your current implementation has a memory leak and adding delete req; after the *this=*req would partially fix it, but it doesn't help if parse() throws an exception after new finished (For example, a std::bad_alloc in the std::string constructor). In general, it is very difficult to maintain exception safety when you have separated new and delete that are not managed by an RAII class (such as std::unique_ptr<T>).
static std::optional<HttpRequest> parse(std::string_view request) {
    // *Parsing*
    HttpRequest req;
    req.method = "GET"; 
    // *And other fields*
    if(/* Some error condition */){
        return {}; // or equivalently, std::nullopt
    }
    // After parsing is finished
    return req;
}

Then the constructor could be written like this,
HttpRequest::HttpRequest(std::string_view request) {
    auto reqOpt = HttpRequest::parse(request); 
    if (!reqOpt) { //Or if you prefer to be explicit, !reqOpt.has_value()
        throw HttpException("Invalid request");
    }
    *this = std::move(*reqOpt); //Or if you prefer to be explicit, std::move(reqOpt.value())
}


Once you have copied the newly constructed object, you need at least to delete it immediately to avoid a memory leak.
*this = *req;
delete req ;

but it does not solve the memory leak from calling parse directly.  How does the caller of parse know how to dispose of the created object, or even that an object was created at all? There is no clear responsibility on the caller here.
Better to have a non-static parse() and call it from the constructor.  It is not clear why it should be static at all.
